# What does a functional integral evaluation look like?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, intuition, motivation, functional-calculus

I've read the Wikipedia page on [functional integration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_integration), but it really isn't very easy to understand. There don't seem to be any online videos on the subject either. In addition, when I search online, I get results for the [Feynman Path integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation). It's a good reference, but it adds a lot of complexities to the problem of understanding functional integration. For instance, quantum mechanics is already hard enough, I can't really parse what's functional integration and what's QM formalism.

Could someone perhaps share some intuition/motivation for why the functional integral is defined the way it is? I'd really like to see a simple, but non-trivial, example worked out. I'm nearly clueless about how an infinite product of infinite bounded integrals converges, so a show-and-tell on how this works out in practice would be great.

Comment: A [start](http://www.mrl.ucsb.edu/~ghf/che230a/ghf_monog_appx_C.pdf).

Comment: @Lucian Definitely a good start. Thanks :)